# iOS/Swift: Use UIView.animate to animate text getting added/removed from UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uitextview

I am adding and removing attributed text from a `UITextView`. I wish to use `UIView.animate` to add an animation to when text is appended to the text view and when that appended text is removed from the  text view. So far, I have this, but it does not cause any noticeable animation on the text view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.textView.attributedText = newAttributedText
}, completion: { finished in
    print("Animation completed")
}

// prints "Animation completed", but no animation occurs
```

Comment: Can you post where are you using this code?

Comment: The `attributedText` (and `text`) attribute is not animatable using simple `UIView` animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate changing of text in that manner. There is a [list of animatable properties of CALayer class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html) and [UIView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html).

Answer (score 1):

Set text cannot be animated by `UIView.animate`. Only changes like transparency, colors, shape, location, etc can be animated by the `UIView.animate`.

Here is an example of animating origin and transparency change with code looks like

```
self.textView.text = "test Animation"
self.textView.alpha = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    var frame = self.textView.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + 50
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 50
    self.textView.frame = frame

    self.textView.alpha = 1

}, completion: { finished in
    print("Animation completed")
})
```

And animation looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (swift 3 ) :

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.2, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
            self.textView2.frame = self.textView2.frame.offsetBy(dx: 20 , dy: 25)
        } )
        animator.startAnimation()
```